# VB.NET ~ How can I encapsulate my code to be used over and over?

Tags: vb.net, browser, encapsulation

I know I seem to ask the same types of questions but with much trial and error I finally got my app to do what I needed it to do. I have a form with a button on it. When clicked it creates a form, a web browser, a picture box, a text box, and a button.

The web browser, picture box, textbox, and the button are all placed onto this form at run time.

My question is now how can I encapsulate this to be used over and over again. I've tried just putting this into a class and creating an instance of the class but I keept getting an error on my document completing stating my code isn't referring to an object.

But here is my code.

Thanks

```
Public Class CaptchaWindow
Dim myform As New Form
Dim webbrowser As New WebBrowser
Dim picturebox As New PictureBox
Dim textbox As New TextBox
Dim submitbtn As New Button
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
ProfileMaker.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
Call myspecs()


AddHandler submitbtn.Click, AddressOf captchasubmit
AddHandler webbrowser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf webcompleteddesignfloat
webbrowser.Navigate("http://www.designfloat.com/register/")

End Sub

Sub myspecs()


'FORM SIZE AND LOCATION
myform.Size = New Drawing.Size(1542, 771)
myform.Location = New Drawing.Point(15, 15)

'WEBBROWSER SIZE AND LOCATION
webbrowser.Size = New Drawing.Size(1000, 577)
webbrowser.Location = New Drawing.Point(12, 181)
webbrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True

'PICTUREBOX SIZE AND LOCATION
picturebox.Size = New Drawing.Size(299, 83)
picturebox.Location = New Drawing.Point(12, 12)
picturebox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D


'TEXBOX SIZE AND LOCATION
textbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(299, 20)
textbox.Location = New Drawing.Point(12, 101)

'BUTTON SIZE AND LOCATION
submitbtn.Size = New Drawing.Size(75, 23)
submitbtn.Location = New Drawing.Point(118, 127)
submitbtn.Text = "Submit"

myform.Controls.Add(webbrowser)
myform.Controls.Add(picturebox)
myform.Controls.Add(textbox)
myform.Controls.Add(submitbtn)
myform.Show()




End Sub

Sub webcompleteddesignfloat()
For Each element As HtmlElement In webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
If element.GetAttribute("name") = "reg_username" Then
element.SetAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Username.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element As HtmlElement In webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
If element.GetAttribute("name") = "reg_email" Then
element.SetAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Email.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element As HtmlElement In webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
If element.GetAttribute("name") = "reg_password" Then
element.SetAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Password.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element As HtmlElement In webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
If element.GetAttribute("name") = "reg_password2" Then
element.SetAttribute("value", ProfileMaker.Password.Text)
End If
Next

If webbrowser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
For Each Captcha As HtmlElement In webbrowser.Document.Images
If Captcha.GetAttribute("src").Contains("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?    c=") Then
picturebox.Load(Captcha.GetAttribute("src"))
End If
Next
End If


End Sub

Sub captchasubmit()

If webbrowser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
For Each Captcha As HtmlElement In webbrowser.Document.Images
If Captcha.GetAttribute("src").Contains("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=") Then
picturebox.Load(Captcha.GetAttribute("src"))
End If
Next
End If

For Each element As HtmlElement In webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
If element.GetAttribute("id") = "recaptcha_response_field" Then
element.SetAttribute("value", textbox.Text)
End If
Next

For Each element As HtmlElement In webbrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
If element.GetAttribute("name") = "submit" Then
element.InvokeMember("click")
End If
Next


myform.Dispose()

End Sub
```

The below part is when I tried to create an instance of this from a class.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
Dim mystuff As New CaptchaClass
mystuff.Handler()
mystuff.captchasubmit()
mystuff.webcompleteddesignfloat()


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you mean by "used over and over again"? Do you just want to call these methods multiple times..if yes how abt using a for loop for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `Imports` your class namespace to the current scope (page) at the beggining of the code

```
Imports Namespace.CaptchaWindow

Class Page1


Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
Dim mystuff As New CaptchaClass
End Sub

End Class
```

Also look at [Namespaces](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/ggaganesh/namespacesinvbdotnet04202005005133am/namespacesinvbdotnet.aspx) if you doesn't know what it is.

Comment: Thanks Thiago - This has helped me alot.